# How to create dynamic class property in typescript

Tags: typescript, class, dynamic

Consider a class like this -

```
class MyClass {
    constructor() {
        const dynamicProperty = {
            name: 'ujjwal gupta',
            setName(value) {
                this.name = value
            }
        };

        for (const key in dynamicProperty) {
            this[key] = dynamicProperty[key];
        }
    }

    getName(){
       return this.name
    }
}
```

this is valid in javascript, but typescript throws error in getName. I can suppress the error by converting to type any but i need the intillisense.

Please help me

## Update 1

My actual use case is -

I have states as object and now i want to create dynamic method to set those states.

```
const states = {
    name:'ujjwal'
},

class MyMutation {
   constructor(states){
     for(const key in states){
        this[key] = (value)=>{
            states[key] = value;
        }
     }  
   }
}
```

these methods are available but i also want my class to be strong typed, so that user can see what methods are available or what other properties are available.

if anyone is interested - this is the project i am working on : https://github.com/ujjwalguptaofficial/godam

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: @caTS updated, check update1.

Comment: Don't add the states to the class then. It's simpler to just put all the states in one property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would avoid dynamic adding of properties, but in some cases this is the only way.

Here is my solution to this, proven by a typescript playground [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=34&ssc=33&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgEwgDwCrmgXigbwLABQUUA2gNYQgBcUAzsAE4CWcA5gLo0CGcIA3IQC%20hQgGMANl1q0oAWRABhSdNyFixAPQaA7tC4NotLiBasoAWiggIM3VFE8oACy4A3PbyhgGAe0hRtJmAnKB4QKFcucQBXCAAaKAAjCHEmCHcoAFsIKjV1ckoaemY2TlDeAQI84lEfOGLo0WAfBgAKAEpVInUe2vrgKAQQOC5MplEABV9IBmA02hp4JDQMKGx8bp6tqBHsmgByaIArI%200oqFZosGAufbjq7fVaCGAAOVGIVsiYnLpGU06G0ewKgwSYtAAdLssBEorEHsDhJstoJKgj1AAzFpQVp9ehQCjhFiDYajcZTPwQWbzQHo7Zg2gFEDsNYk3bk6ZUuY2JnsSqIh5Ih6sF7vbIdIHbAzAaIMOCgpzgqEfQVCEQEPEDFj0HiiGFwCDaOSKZS0DpojV1Wg%20cQQCHiHysVram5wPUQkVvD4ddoWrTROBY2YBrjAFLhOwOOBwHwDBzicQKwyij50Fh6qBBTMyIbs%20PicJcMCQRAQBAJRLRAaRxz5zMDYK%20aKsELBaBLFDoSCEF26iAkABEzy92QH7FaA4NRu%20sQHvvVeJtdodTt7brtnrFn3a86qBCAA):

```js
type IndexType = {
  [key: string]: any;
}

class MyClass {
    //we are saying - yes we can have any prope with any value, believe me:
    [key: string]: any;

    constructor() {
        const dynamicProperties: IndexType = {
            name: 'ujjwal gupta',
            setName(value: string) {
                this.name = value
            }
        };

        for (const key in dynamicProperties) {
            this[key] = dynamicProperties[key];
        }
    }

    getName(){
       return this.name
    }
}

const instance = new MyClass();


// this will print "ujjwal gupta" to the console
console.log(instance.getName());

//unfortunately we cannot call the setName since it is dynamically appended, but we can call it through the IndexType
instance["setName"]("new value");

// now it will print "new value" to the console
console.log(instance.getName());
```

Comment: but we loose the typing here right ? when i call getName() - it should return string type but its returning type any.

Comment: is there anyway i can create typing for class property dynamically ?

Comment: You cannot generate typings dynamically. The Typescript types are "syntax sugar" on top of javascript, in the end it produces javascript which is executed.

Comment: Ok accepting the answer for now, but if anyone finds a way to add typing please let me know.

Comment: @UjjwalKumarGupta To add typing, you would essentially redeclare the properties you want to dynamically add... So that's why I'm asking why you need to do this. If you tell us why, we can probably come up with a better alternative.

Comment: thanks @caTS, i have updated the question - please check update1.